# Why does subselect make 2 queries instead of one?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a simple Restaurant Entity that has a List of Votes ( some fields and methods are omitted for brevity ).

```
public class Restaurant extends AbstractNamedEntity {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "restaurant", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonManagedReference
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<Vote> votes;
}
```

Here is another side of the relationship

```
 public class Vote extends AbstractBaseEntity {
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonBackReference
    private Restaurant restaurant;
}
```

When I try to fetch data using Spring data JPA findAll() method and then convert it to DTOs

```
  public static RestaurantResponseDTO toRestaurantDto(Restaurant restaurant) {

        return new RestaurantResponseDTO(restaurant.getId(), restaurant.getName(),
                restaurant.getAddress(), getRestaurantVoteCount(restaurant));
    }
    public static long getRestaurantVoteCount(Restaurant restaurant) {
    var votes = restaurant.getVotes();
    if (votes == null) return 0;
    return  votes.stream().filter(vote -> vote.getVoteDate().equals(LocalDate.now())).count();
}
```

these are the SQLs I have:

```
Hibernate: 
select
    restaurant0_.id as id1_1_,
    restaurant0_.name as name2_1_,
    restaurant0_.address as address3_1_ 
from
    restaurant restaurant0_

Hibernate: 
select
    votes0_.restaurant_id as restaura3_4_1_,
    votes0_.id as id1_4_1_,
    votes0_.id as id1_4_0_,
    votes0_.restaurant_id as restaura3_4_0_,
    votes0_.user_id as user_id4_4_0_,
    votes0_.vote_date as vote_dat2_4_0_ 
from
    vote votes0_ 
where
    votes0_.restaurant_id in (
        select
            restaurant0_.id 
        from
            restaurant restaurant0_
    )
```

I thought that Subselect needs only 1, why do I have 2?

Comment: It's probably due to the relation being lazily evaluated so `getRestaurantVoteCount()` probably triggers the second query (i.e. you first get the restaurant only and `votes` isn't initialized yet). If the relation was eager it should do it in one query.

Comment: @Thomas I've added implementation of getRestaurantVoteCount() to the topic.
Changing FetchType to Eager does not make a difference :(

Comment: Thinking some more about this and brushing up my already fading Hibernate skills ( :( ), I realized you seem to have a misconception here. SUBSELECT will do 2 queries but it will use a subselect (as far as I know the query you used to load the restaurants) to decide which votes to load. It thus can lazily load votes for multiple restaurants at once.  Also, SUBSELECT couldn't return any data from the subselect so that wouldn't make sense. I assume you're confusing it with JOIN which should do it in one query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, what you see is expected hibernate behavior. See [this section](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-fetchmode-subselect) of the hibernate documentation.

Hibernate is going to avoid the N+1 query issue by generating a single SQL statement to initialize all `votes` collections for all `Restaurant` entities that were previously fetched. Instead of using passing all entity identifiers, Hibernate simply reruns the previous query that fetched the `Restaurant` entities.

P.S. As for the `FetchMode.JOIN` option, please note that as it's mentioned [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-fetchmode-join):

> The reason why we are not using a JPQL query to fetch multiple Department entities is because the `FetchMode.JOIN` strategy would be overridden by the query fetching directive.
>
> To fetch multiple relationships with a JPQL query, the `JOIN FETCH` directive must be used instead.

So, I guess the most flexible way for your case would be to write own JPQL query and use `JOIN FETCH` directive where it's needed.